Making undo/redo work with relationships: my mistake or SwiftData bug?
I'm trying to take advantage of SwiftData's automatic undo/redo support in a SwiftUI macOS app. I've overcome one of the wrinkles of getting it to work with relationships, but am stuck on another and wondering if I'm missing something or if it's in fact a SwiftData bug.
I essentially have a one-to-many relationship between parent and child entities. Undoing and redoing insertion or deletion of parent entities works fine. Undoing insertion of child entities also works fine (this required adding the object to the model context before setting the parent relationship). But redoing insertion or undoing deletion of child entities doesn't work. The child simply won't reappear.
Here's a simple test app to reproduce the problem:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: Parent.self, isUndoEnabled: true)
    }
}

@Model
final class Parent {
    @Attribute(.unique) var timestamp = Date.now
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Child.parent)
    var children = [Child]()
    
    init() {}
}

@Model
final class Child {
    @Attribute(.unique) var timestamp = Date.now
    var parent: Parent?
    
    init() {}
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var parents: [Parent]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(parents.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp })) { parent in
                HStack {
                    Text("Parent \(parent.timestamp.description)")
                    Button("Add Child") {
                        let child = Child()
                        modelContext.insert(child)
                        child.parent = parent
                    }
                    Button("Delete") {
                        modelContext.delete(parent)
                    }
                }
                ForEach(parent.children.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp })) { child in
                    HStack {
                        Text("Child \(child.timestamp.description)")
                        Button("Delete") {
                            modelContext.delete(child)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding([.leading], 20)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button("Add Parent") {
                modelContext.insert(Parent())
            }
        }
    }
}



Removing the delete rule doesn't make a difference. Setting the parent property to nil before deletion also doesn't help.
Am I doing something wrong or should report this as a bug to Apple?

After some more testing I've found that the child objects actually do get added back into the model context when undoing deletion or redoing addition, but their parent property doesn't get correctly restored and is nil, so they don't show up as children of the parents. So the problem is actually that undo/redo doesn't seem to work on changes to properties referencing other Model objects.

Did you find a solution meanwhile?

The bugs have changed somewhat between macOS 14 and 15.0, but it's still broken. I understand it better now and filed new feedback. Basically, with 1-to-many relationships, undo/redo often produces an inconsistent state in memory, with the child missing from the array in the parent, despite having a non-nil parent value itself. Once the model context is saved (e.g. when switching away from the app), the internal inconsistency is resolved, but often wrongly, with the final state not matching the expected result of the user actions. 1-to-1 relationships are less buggy but also not 100% reliable.

@AmarSagoo I am experiencing exactly this! Did you find a solution?

@ManeManero Some of the bugs have been fixed in macOS 15.1, but a few remain (last tested in 15.1.1): in 1–many relationships, undoing the deletion or unlinking of a child is buggy; in 1–1 relationships, undoing then redoing the nullification of a relationship doesn't work. Can't find a workaround, so will just keep reporting and waiting for Apple to fix this.
